# Maven: modify artifact version depending on day of the week

Tags: maven, maven-versions-plugin

one of my colleagues, gave me the task of modifying the version of our Maven artifacts depending on the day of the week.

Monday through Saturday: SNAPSHOT version.

Sunday: Without SNAPSHOT

Is there a way to make this idea a success?

I can't make it work, I've tried different ways and failed again and again.
I thought one of the best ideas/tries was to dump maven.timestamp into a variable and replace it with regex-property@build-helper-maven-plugin. And Failed.

But until the plugins are executed, the version is already set.

I have no idea if this is even possible and if so how I can do it.

Regards

**Edit1:**

The Version of artifact builds containing Week of the Year, for example 1911.
We have more than 20 Java projects, all connected via a parent pom.xml, or connected via a another parent that inherits from the "master" parent.

Builds are running on TFS.
Depending on the change of a project, all dependent projects are built bottom-up.
Therefore, I would/must implement the logic already in parent.pom, so that all projects, and derived "child-parents", get this logic processed.

Comment: If you only use the day of the week you have duplicated versions after a week which should never happen...apart from that why do you need that?

Comment: If you want a release build once a week, there are way easier ways to achieve this...